# VB.net add WebView2 on the fly

Tags: vb.net, webview2

Could you please help me with this. Using the old WebBrowser control on VB.net I would do something like:

```
Public wbx As WebBrowser

wbx = New WebBrowser
wbx.BringToFront()
wbx.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

Add Handler wbx.NewWindow, AddressOf WebBrowser_NewWindow
Me.Controls.Add(wbx)


Private Sub WebBrowser_NewWindow(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
   Dim newUrl As String = wbx.StatusText
   e.Cancel = True
   wbx.Navigate(newUrl)
End Sub
```

How would I achieve the same using the new WebView2 control so that I can create the control programmatically on the fly when needed? Any insight is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where  is the code that is shown floating in the breeze? It must be in some type of method. Why is `wbx As WebBrowser` Public? Where is this declaration located?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms

Comment: I had quite a few problems with the new `WevView2` control and reverted to mangy old one - which generally works as-advertised - tho missing some contemporary features. The MS dev I liaised with admitted that it wasn't yet "fully cooked". I also looked at a couple of third-party browser options based on Chrome but they were too "heavy" for the app I was developing.

Comment: @Mary `wbx` is public in the main module of the code so that it can be accessed throughout the application.

Comment: @Mary I've already checked this link
learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/… and implemented it, but the main problem is that I don't want to add the component to the form at design time, rather I'd like to add it at run time.

Comment: @SteveCinq The old WebBrowser control is not supported anymore and most of the sites don't work on it, so I am obliged to move to something new. I've tried 3rd party options but as you said they are very heavy.

Comment: @Carol I know what you mean re: support. The problem I had was with Google SSO not working properly but I found a solution to that which improved compatibility (adding a HKCU Registry setting). I can provide more info if you tell us what the issue with the old browser is (if it's a specific one).

Comment: @Carol Re: `Public` scope, have you considered using `Friend` to keep things contained?

Comment: To add it at runtime, you basically replace `WebBrowser` with `WebView2` and set the properties and events. You still need the package and Edge CANARY.

Comment: @PoulBak I already tried that but it seems not supported and use different functions and calls.

Comment: @SteveCinq The scope is not my problem, my main problem is being able to add the browser at run-time.

Comment: Check the WebView2 reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2?view=WebView2-dotnet-1.0.664.37 where all properties, methods and events are explained.

Comment: BTW: You should set `Parent` to your form - as the first thing after creating the `WebView2`.

Comment: @PoulBak I already checked the documentation, it's not like the old WebBrowser component. I can't find any option that allows me to add it on the fly. That's my main issue and not the scope or parent thing.

Comment: We need more info to help you. Please show your code (that doesn't work), so we can help you. Have you installed the Nuget package into your project? And installed Microsoft Edge CANARY build? What .Net version do you use?

Comment: @PoulBak My dear, I just want to initiate the new WebView2 as I used to do with the old WebBrowser component as I was unable to achieve that using the new WebView2. I was able to run it successfully by placing the WebView2 control directly on the form but the question is, is it possible to add it on the fly during run-time as I did in the code above?

Comment: Have you included:`Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms` in top of your file?

Comment: @PoulBak Yes, already did that. But still not able to add the WebView2 to the form after it has loaded.